# Is there a way to concatenate strings with a delimiter that a user will never be able to enter across languages and keyboard types?

Tags: java, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have 5 strings I want to concatenate for storage. I can not store them separately, I also can not serialize the object that contains them. I can however store one string variable.

Is there a way to add these strings together, separated by a character only another programmer could enter so that said string can be split using that character later? Is there a unique escape code or something of the sort?

This may be bad design, and I am changing the system completely, I am just curious if it is possible.

Comment: Is a programmer not a user? What could differentiate them that would make this possible?

Comment: Are you limited to separating by a single character?

Comment: @Pillar, good point, however my code will not be used by anyone except me, as far as I can see. So if a keyboard can't type it, it should work for the unique delimiter. That is why I was thinking about an escape code. I figured there may be one I do not know about, but I could not find anything on Google

Comment: Typically, you do what Jason suggests below. Find something ridiculously unlikely to be part of your dataset.

Comment: You could serialize your data as a JSON array, or encode the strings in base64 or something. That'll be much safer than hoping they don't contain certain characters or character sequences.

Comment: @Jason, No, I can separate them by anything. I am going to use String.split() to get the Strings back to their original form.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not control your input, then you can't guarantee anything.

It's that simple.

Instead, you should pick a delimiter, then escape that delimiter.

Consider, the ubiquitous TAB.

To escape tabs, using the \ as your escape character:

```
    field1 = field1.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\t", "\\\t");
```

Then you have to parse the line back, which is straight forward.

Here's a complete example. Obviously you would use string builders and something more interesting than println with your fields.

```
public class x {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String field1 = "field\t1";
        String field2 = "field\\2";
        String field3 = "field3";

        field1 = field1.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\t", "\\\t");
        field2 = field2.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\t", "\\\t");
        field3 = field3.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\t", "\\\t");

        String line = field1 + "\t" + field2 + "\t" + field3;

        System.out.println("Encoded line: " + line);    

        char chars[] = line.toCharArray();
        String field = "";
        boolean escaped = false;
        for(char c : chars) {
            if (escaped) {
                field = field + c;
                escaped = false;
            } else {
                switch (c) {
                    case '\\':
                        escaped = true;
                        break;
                    case '\t':
                        System.out.println("field = " + field);
                        field = "";
                        break;
                    default:
                        field = field + c;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!field.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("field = " + field);
        }
    }
}
```

Addenda:

I don't know what XML has to do with anything, there's no mention of XML in your question.

You mentioned in another comment:

> Playlists are universalized in Android and playlists not created in my
>   app will not be able to stick to my rules.

That means you don't control the input, since they "will not be able to stick to my rules". So, you have no idea what they'll send. You have no idea how they may be using that character that "can never be used". Ideally this isn't a security issue, but these are classic examples of how data gets injected where you don't necessarily want it to be injected.

So, that means you need to be more precise on your rules rather than "hoping" someone will send properly formatted data. By using an actual syntax that will accept "anything", then this is not a problem at all.

You can use my simple TAB example, which works for any character, really, as it's the escaping that makes it work, the actual character used is irrelevant.

Or you can use a more sophisticated syntax. JSON was mentioned, as it's ubiquitous.

Either one is precise, and can take field values of "anything", imposing no limitation on what the users can or can't type. Who knows what magic keyboards are coming next. Welcome to the world of Emojis.

Finally, if we've learned anything in the recent past, assuming that the data coming in to you socket is matching your spec and does not need to be validated is just plain dangerous. It may not be your program talking to your port, it could be anything.

More addenda:

> I was referring to XML because when an XML file is written and Java,
>   how could they determine what is an XML tag, and what is in between
>   the tag?

Because an XML document is represented by an internal data structure (for example, the standard DOM). Using the DOM as an example, the DOM DOES know "what is an XML tag, and what is in between the tag", and when it serializes the DOM to XML, it properly escapes any special characters used by XML itself using things like '<' for the '<' character when they appear "between the tags".

When parsing XML, the parser knows where it's parsing an element tag or not, so it knows whether the data it is parsing is between a tag or not. XMLs grammar describes the rules for this.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your first statement. XML files must be passed somehow, I haven't seen the Java XML parser get tripped up with this sort of thing.

Comment: I was referring to XML because when an XML file is written and Java, how could they determine what is an XML tag, and what is in between the tag? The file is processed at some point, I imagine as a string. It was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically choose your delimiter for each record you are going to store. Put the delimiter as the first characters in the stored record.

For example, you might choose to have a three-character delimiter. When you need to concatenate and store, examine the strings and choose a delimiter that does not exist in any of the strings.

Let's say your strings are: `Dynamically choose`, `your delimiter` and `for each record`. Decide your delimiter characters and start looping through all of the permutations. Let's say that the first permutation is `aaa`. You check for `aaa` in each of the strings and find that it does not appear as a substring in any of the strings. If it had, you would have moved on to try `aab`.

Your delimiter is `aaa` so your concatenated record is

`aaaDynamically chooseaaayour delimiteraaafor each record`

To recover your items from the record, strip off the first three characters to get the delimiter. `String.split` by the delimiter and you have your individual strings in an array.